# Creating a function that takes arguments and passes variables

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, global-variables

I am creating a script that will locate a field in a text file and get the value that I need.

First used the file() function to load my txt into an array by line.
Then  I use explode() to create an array for the strings on a selected line. 
I assign labels to the array's to describe a $Key and a $Value.

```
$line = file($myFile);
$arg = 3
$c = explode(" ", $line[$arg]);
$key = strtolower($c[0]);
if (strpos($c[2], '~') !== false) {
 $val = str_replace('~', '.', $c[2]);
}else{
$val = $c[2];
}
```

This works fine but that is a lot of code to have to do over and over again for everything I want to get out of the txt file.  So I wanted to create a function that I could call with an argument that would return the value of $key and $val.  And this is where I am failing:

```
<?php

    /**
     * @author Jason Moore
     * @copyright 2014
     */
    global $line;
    $key = '';
    $val = '';
    $myFile = "player.txt";
    $line = file($myFile); //file in to an array
    $arg = 3;
    $Character_Name = 3
    function get_plr_data2($arg){
    global $key;
    global $val;
    $c = explode(" ", $line[$arg]);
    $key = strtolower($c[0]);
    if (strpos($c[2], '~') !== false) {
     $val = str_replace('~', '.', $c[2]);
    }else{
    $val = $c[2];
    }
    return;
    }
    get_plr_data2($Character_Name);
    echo "This character's ",$key,' is ',$val;
    ?>
```

I thought that I covered the scope with setting  the values in the main and then setting them a global within the function.  I feel like I am close but I am just missing something.
I feel like there should be something like `return $key,$val;` but that doesn't work.  I could return an Array but then I would end up typing just as much code to the the info out of the array.

I am missing something with the function and the function argument to.  I would like to pass and argument  example :  `get_plr_data2($Character_Name);` the argument identifies the line that we are getting the data from.

Any help with this would be more than appreciated.

::Updated::

Thanks to the answers I got past passing the Array.

But my problem is depending on the arguments I put in `get_plr_data2($arg)` the number of values differ.

I figured that I could just set the Max of num values I could get but this doesn't work at all of course because I end up with undefined offsets instead.

```
$a = $cdata[0];$b = $cdata[1];$c = $cdata[2];
$d = $cdata[3];$e = $cdata[4];$f = $cdata[5];
$g = $cdata[6];$h = $cdata[7];$i = $cdata[8];
$j = $cdata[9];$k = $cdata[10];$l = $cdata[11];
return array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l);
```

Now I am thinking that I can use the count function `myCount = count($c);` to either amend or add more values creating the offsets I need.  Or a better option is if there was a way I could generate the return array(), so that it would could the number of values given for array and return all the values needed.  I think that maybe  I am just making this a whole lot more difficult than it is.

Thanks again for all the help and suggestions

Comment: If you want to learn PHP, please omit using global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_plr_data2($arg){
   $myFile = "player.txt";
   $line = file($myFile); //file in to an array
   $c = explode(" ", $line[$arg]);
   $key = strtolower($c[0]);
   if (strpos($c[2], '~') !== false) {
    $val = str_replace('~', '.', $c[2]);
   }else{
   $val = $c[2];
   }
   return array($key,$val);
}
```

Using:

```
list($key,$val) = get_plr_data2(SOME_ARG);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in 2 way

1. you can return both values in an array

   `function get_plr_data2($arg){
    /* do what you have to do    */
    $output=array();
    $output['key'] =$key;
    $output['value']= $value;

    return $output;
   }`

   and use the array in your main function
2. you can use reference so that you can return multiple values

   `function get_plr_data2($arg,&$key,&$val){
   /* do job */

    }
    //use the function as
    $key='';
    $val='';
    get_plr_data2($arg,$key,$val);`

   what ever you do to $key in function it will affect the main functions $key

Comment: The problem I am having now is returning the array because are a variety in the number of values returned. I'll put this issue above

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking it.  Thanks for all they help guys.  this is what I finally came up with thanks to your guidance:

```
<?php

$ch_file = "Thor";
$ch_name = 3;
$ch_lvl = 4;
$ch_clss = 15;


list($a,$b)= get_char($ch_file,$ch_name);//
Echo $a,': ',$b; // Out Puts values from the $cdata array.

function get_char($file,$data){
$myFile = $file.".txt";
$line = file($myFile);
$cdata =  preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line[$data]));
return $cdata;
}
```

Brand new to this community, thanks for all the patience.